# Converting GeoTIFF Elevation Data to 3D ZXY Tiles

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, 3d, terrain, cesium

I have a GeoTIFF file which includes elevation data. I visualized the TIFF by pyplot:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
# Open the TIFF file
tiff_file = "./dem/tif1.tif"
dataset = gdal.Open(tiff_file, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
# Read elevation data as a NumPy array
elevation_data = dataset.ReadAsArray()
# Get the dimensions of the elevation data
rows, cols = elevation_data.shape
# Create mesh grid using numpy.meshgrid
x = np.arange(cols)
y = np.arange(rows)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Create the surface plot
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, elevation_data, cmap='terrain')
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Now I'm looking to convert a GeoTIFF file with elevation data into 3D terrain using ZXY tiles. I've attempted to use the '3d-tiles-tools' provided by Cesium, but I'm uncertain whether this tool directly supports the conversion of GeoTIFF files into a 3D tileset.

If it does, how do I achieve this conversion?

Comment: what are ZXY tiles?

Comment: do you mean? https://github.com/CesiumGS/quantized-mesh

Comment: yes, z is zoom level and x and y are evaluated by number of tiles in each zoom level, a common format for viewing map:https://enonline.supermap.com/iServer9D/Subject_introduce/Cache/MapCache/TileFormat/ZXY_format.htm

Comment: you can use https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder

Comment: do you know whats the exact command i must use?